# Can't free char* in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, free

I'm currently developping a project in C++ and, in a module, I have a problem : I can't free my pointers. 
The problem is the manipulation of char* with strings.
I need to use char * for the openssl lib and strtok (I know this is not the only way to do it but I prefer to use it since it seems more difficult in a "C++ way").

I don't understand why I can't free the commented char*, ("unvalid free pointer, Abandon")

Do you have an idea and a solution?
Thank's

```
string* traitement_req1(string& affectation) {
         string nom;
         char* statut=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
         char* hash=(char*)malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*sizeof(char));
         char* token=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
         string readAffectation;
         string hashlist;
         string hashS;
         string * finalList = new string[2];
         string listnom;
         string fichier = "test.txt";
         ifstream file(fichier.c_str(), ios::in); 
         if(file){
                 char* line= (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char)); 
                 string sline=line;
                 while (getline(file,sline)){       
                         line=(char*)sline.c_str(); 
                         nom = string(strtok(line, " "));
                         statut = strtok(NULL," ");
                         readAffectation =string(strtok(NULL," "));
                         if (affectation == readAffectation){
                                 SHA_CTX ctx;
                                 SHA1_Init(&ctx);
                                 SHA1_Update(&ctx, statut, strlen(statut));
                                 SHA1_Final((unsigned char*)hash, &ctx);
                                 hashS=string(hash,strlen(hash));
                                 hashlist += hashS; 
                                 hashlist += "\n";
                                 listnom  += nom; 
                                 listnom  += "\n";
                         }
                } 
                file.close();
                //free(hash);
                //free(line);
                //free(statut);
                finalList[0] = hashlist;
                finalList[1] = listnom;
                return finalList;
        }
        else {
                printf("error : ouverture impossible!\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }                       
}
```

Comment: is there any good reason why you use `malloc` and `free`? I have my doubts.

Comment: Why are you even using `malloc`? I assume `SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH` and `BUF_SIZE` are constants, so just use an array on the stack instead. No need to free anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the question about why you use old C-style strings when programming C++, here is a big problem:

You allocate memory for `line` like this

```
char* line= (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

Then a couple of lines down you do

```
line=(char*)sline.c_str();
```

This changes `line` so it no longer points to the memory you allocated, attempting to free it now will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You have the same problem with the `statut` pointer.

A couple of related notes:

- Every time you find yourself doing a C-style cast, you are probably doing something you should not be doing.
- The data returned by the [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is considered *read-only*, trying to modify it leads to undefined behavior too. And modify that data you do, the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) function *modifies* the string you pass to it.

Answer (score 1):

`line` is overwritten by something not allocated via `malloc()` at `line=(char*)sline.c_str();`. Do not `free()` it.

`statut` is overwritten by something not allocated via `malloc()` at `statut = strtok(NULL," ");`. Do not `free()` it.

I didn't find any overwriting of `hash` in this function, but its buffer may be too small to store the string with terminating null-character.